# Spark ML Pipelines: unseen label exception when classifying new examples

Tags: classification, apache-spark-mllib

I cannot find how to use a Spark ML Pipeline to classify a new set of instances (with unknown labels).
All the examples I find are based on a test set with already known labels (which are only used to evaluate the performance of the classification).

I have the following pipeline:

```
    StringIndexer indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("category").setOutputCol("categoryIndex");
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words");
    HashingTF hashingTF = new HashingTF().setNumFeatures(NUM_FEATURES).setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol())
            .setOutputCol("rawFeatures");
    IDF idf = new IDF().setInputCol(hashingTF.getOutputCol()).setOutputCol("rescaledFeatures");

    NaiveBayes naiveBayes = new NaiveBayes().setFeaturesCol(idf.getOutputCol()).setLabelCol("categoryIndex");
    Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
            .setStages(new PipelineStage[] { indexer, tokenizer, hashingTF, idf, naiveBayes });
```

It works perfect, both fitting the estimators and running the transformers (against a test set, which contains gold labels)

But when I try to use the same pipeline for a "real" example for which there is no gold label (the label is precisely what we want to obtain), the StringIndexer which is part of the pipeline throws an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unseen label: UNKNOWN.
```

UNKNOWN is the fake label I have set when programatically creating a new Dataset element with the new unseen examples, and of course such label was not present in the training set. I understand why this error is raised, but is there a way to tell the pipeline that I am no longer "training" or "evaluating", but using it for real classification?
How can I proceed to build a valid input for the pipeline up from a new example (with no known label) to classify it?

Being this my very first question in stackoverflow, hope I have explained it clear enough.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution myself.

TL;DR: `StringIndexer` should be placed outside the *pipeline*.

Transform the initial dataset with the `StringIndexer` to obtain each label index, but do not include the transformation in the *pipeline*. Then set an `IndexToString` transformer at the end of the *pipeline* to convert the predicted indexes (the outcomes of the *ML* algorithm employed for classification/regression) back to categorical labels.

This way, when the *pipeline* model is stored for later use in production, there will be no `StringIndexer` causing the aforementioned problem, and the `IndexToString` will interpret the outcomes of the prediction model to output meaningful labels.